# Azure Table Storage rejects an entity with a Property whose value is an Interface

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I have a type called "Comment" that I'm saving to Azure Table Storage. Since a comment can be about any number of other types, I created an interface which all of these types implement, and then put a property of type ICommentable on the comment. So Comment has a property called About of type ICommentable.

When I try to save a Comment to Azure Table Storage, if the Comment.About property has a value, I get the worthless invalid input error. However, if there is no value for Comment.About, I have no problem. Why would this be?

Comment.About is not the only property that is a reference type. For example, Comment.From is a reference type, but the Comment.About is the only property of a type that is an interface.

Fails:

```
var comment = new Comment();
        comment.CommentText = "It fails!";
        comment.PartitionKey = "TEST";
        comment.RowKey = "TEST123";
        comment.About = sow1;
        comment.From = person1;
```

Works:

```
var comment = new Comment();
        comment.CommentText = "It works!";
        comment.PartitionKey = "TEST";
        comment.RowKey = "TEST123";
        //comment.About = sow1;
        comment.From = person1;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Windows Azure table storage can store only a handful of types, none of which are the ICommentable type you created: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179338.aspx.

Comment: Thanks smarx - that makes sense, and I actually knew that. The thing that puzzles me is that any reference type is automatically ignored anyway - so why the error? I wasn't trying to save this property, but I have to go to the extra work of stripping it off before saving since it throws the error.

Comment: I didn't realize reference types were ignored. But isn't `string` a reference type?

Comment: Uuuhhh, you have me there. I misused the term reference type - I meant a property that references another class. So in the example above, both the About and From properties are references to another type. The From property is always a Person type. But this property is ignored by the Azure table service - no error, but it's definitely not saved in any way. But the From, which is a property of type ICommentable, causes an error if it has a value.

Comment: @AndrewBSchultz Interesting. I thought every public property was saved with the entity.

Comment: now I'm uncomfortable, because you're the expert and maybe I'm wrong. But in my experience, those things aren't saved. I mean how would it be - would it go out to the heap and then grab the referenced object and save it? Because Person isn't one of the types that your link says can be saved.

Comment: @AndrewBSchultz I'm not saying it would work. I'm saying an error would occur when a public property wasn't of a valid type.

Comment: @AndrewBSchultz But I don't have a Windows machine handy to try it on, and you have the code in front of you. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The Azure Table Storage Client does not support granular means of controlling which properties are persistable.

You may wish to check out my open source project on CodePlex which allows fine grain control over which fields/properties to persist to table storage and how to serialize them. (http://lucifurestash.codeplex.com/)

Edit: Fixed typo + clarifications.